# Finding all the values within a band in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, band

I have an image composite which includes a day of year band. When I display the band using `Map.addLayer` and stretch by 100% in the Visualization Parameters I can see that the range of values is 151-281.

How can I get a list of all of the values within this range, i.e. a list of all the unique values of 'doy'? It should not be a long list as the composite image was derived from Sentinel 2 images restricted to a 5 month window. I just need to print the list. 'aoi' is a multi-polygon shapefile.

````js
//Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return ee.Image(image.updateMask(mask)
  .divide(10000).copyProperties(qa)).set('system:time_start', qa.get('system:time_start'));
}

// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
  var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2017-06-01', '2017-10-15')
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(aoi)})//To clip all images to aoi
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  //Select required bands only
                  .select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'QA60')
                  //Apply cloud mask
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

//Function to calculate redEdgeNDVI
var add_reNDVI = function(image){
  //Create band variables
  var redEdge = image.select('B5');
  var NIR = image.select('B8');
  var redEdgeNDVI = NIR.subtract(redEdge).divide(NIR.add(redEdge)).rename('reNDVI');
    return image.addBands(redEdgeNDVI);
};

//Map sentinel 2 collection to reNDVI
var S2_reNDVI = S2.map(add_reNDVI);

//Function to create DOY band
var addDate = function(image){
  var doy = image.date().getRelative('day', 'year');
  var doyBand = ee.Image.constant(doy).uint16().rename('doy');
  doyBand = doyBand.updateMask(image.select('reNDVI').mask());
    return image.addBands(doyBand);
};

//Map sentinel 2 collection to DOY function
var S2Date = S2_reNDVI.map(addDate);

// Make a "max redEdgeNDVI" pixel composite taking max reNDVI from all images 
var S2_max_reNDVI = S2Date.qualityMosaic('reNDVI');

//Add DOY layer
Map.addLayer(S2_max_reNDVI, {bands:['doy'], palette: ['ffeda0', 'feb24c', 'f03b20']}, 'DOY for Max reNDVI pixel composite');```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are interested in actual pixel values, so you should use reduceRegions. You could use the reducer ee.Reducer.minMax() to get the min and max value.
However, you want a list of all values present. For that you can use the reducer ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(). That returns a dictionary with the number of pixels per valid pixel input, which are the keys. So if you get those keys, you will have a list of valid pixels in your area of interest.

ReduceRegions returns a feature collection. So to get those keys, we need to map the output, make a list of all the keys and get only the distinct values:

```
// Get the list of values from the mosaic image
var freqHist = S2_max_reNDVI.select('doy')
        .reduceRegions({reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), collection: table, scale: 20});
// rewrite the distionary
var values = ee.List(freqHist.map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Feature(feat);
  var vals = ee.Dictionary(feat.get('histogram')).keys();
  return ee.Feature(null, {vals: vals});
}).aggregate_array('vals')).flatten().distinct();
print(values);
```

Note that I increased the scale a bit to overcome memory issues.

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/123ba052ecaded6bbff69dc5b956af90)

Comment: This works when aoi is a single polygon. When I run it with a multi-polygon (11493 polygons but total area < single polygon) I get an error message. "Earth Engine memory capacity exceeded." I get the same message when I try to export using the same multi-polygon file. As the imageCollection is already clipped to the multi-polygon file at the start (```.map(function(image){return image.clip(aoi)})```), do the values change depending on the geometry file I use in the histogram or do they remain the same because the imageCollection was already clipped in the earlier process?

Comment: It should not take into account all masked values you created when clipping. Does it work when you change the argument 'geometry' in reduceRegion() to aoi.bounds(): https://code.earthengine.google.com/232fdd5d0ab717f293929bbb302a9bf0 ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I get the error message "aoi.bounds is not a function". I also tried it in your script with my multi-polygon and got the same error message. Your script worked fine with your m-p. My m-p is a shapefile I uploaded as an asset and is described by GEE as a 'table'. The single polygon is also a shapefile and was uploaded and imported in the same way.

Comment: If you upload it as a 'table', it is a featureCollection, containing a multipolygon. You should first get the geometry from that featureCollection using ee.Feature(table.first()).geometry(), assuming that your featureCollection contains of only one feature. Otherwise, use table.union(). https://code.earthengine.google.com/aaca673edbcc7e4ef51e426ab74f91af . If it still runs out of computation, you could consider increasing the scale parameters or export the result as a table/featureCollection.

Comment: Your code works but when I add my m-p file and use ee.Feature(table.first()).geometry(); I get a list of 4 values and only 1 polygon is displayed. When I use var aoi = ee.Feature(table.union()).geometry(); I get “Image (Error) Element.geometry: Unable to use a collection in an algorithm that requires a feature or image. This may happen when trying to use a collection of collections where a collection of features is expected; use flatten, or map a function to convert inner collections to features. Use.... ”. I added my aoi: https://code.earthengine.google.com/c31af1ab4583618e2fabd540aeb4340c

Comment: I changed the answer to reflect your data. It is not a multipolygon but a featurecollection containing features with polygons and multipolygons. Therefore, you need reduceRegions()

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, this worked great.